# Search engine using python for bookmarked sites

Tags: python, search-engine

The idea I have is to build a search engine based on my bookmarks file which I have in CSV format.

The motivation behind this idea is that I have a large number of bookmarks related to the educational resources which I want to be able to search and find related content for a particular topic or subject.

I am not a very good programmer(I can write simple programs in c++ and java) and have recently started learning python.

Is the implementation of such project possible in one month?

I have searched and found that a CSV module exists in python language and the only idea I can get is from the udacity CS101 course of building a search engine using python.

My question is whether this is possible and where to start ?

Comment: Please provide any code you already have in your question.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't started the project.I wanted to know if this is possible or it is not a good idea. Once I start coding , I will post my coding doubts here with code.

Comment: 1) everything is possible. 2) whether it is a good idea or not is completely opinion. 3) start by reading tutorial about this CSV module. => vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a search engine both in Perl and Python at work. The first one was put together for a production problem in great haste and took 2 hours to build, from concept to run. I want to open-source the final version, but not sure where to start since it was work done for employer. Anyhow, here's the algorithm:

```
st={} #dictonary for search engine tree
for bokm in bookmarks:
    bokm=re.sub('\W_',' ',bokm).toupper() #filter out junk chars
    ct = st;   #cursor for traversing and building our tree
    for c in bokm.split():
        if not ct[c]: ct[c]={}
        ct = ct[c]
```

At this point you have a dict-tree of chars that comprise your bookmarks. It will only find matches from beginning of bookmark, you can modify the algorithm to hash bookmarks starting from any word instead. Make sure to pprint.pprint(st) to see the beauty of it for yourself.

So let's say you are searching now and typed the word "dog":

```
def search(word, st):
    word=re.sub('\W_',' ',word).toupper() #pass word through same filter!
    ct = st #init our cursor
    for c in word.split():
        try:
            ct = ct[c]     #traverse the tree
        except KeyError:
            return False    #pattern diverged, no match
    return True #run out of word chars and every character matched. Found a match!
```

You can pretty much plug this in and start using. It does not return WHICH pattern it matched, you need to record that at the ends of search tree branches and recursively traverse the subtree after the last search word character to print all bookmarks that matched.

PS: There are many possible ways to implement word search. The beauty of this method is that it find matches almost instantly, always, regardless of the size of your bookmarks file. The second benefit is that search() can be modified to show you results as you type, with each key press, because it traverses our bookmark tree character by character, and it will do it instantaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - CS101 from Udacity is a good starting point. I completed this class 1-2 years ago. It can guide you step by step in building a search engine using python. Working at an average pace, you can complete the class in ~2 weeks. After understanding what has been done there, you can switch to your bookmarks input.