# Search or filter implementation?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a list of items. For illustration purposes: {apple, apples, orange, cheese, fruit}. I would like to add a search bar that would be able to provide a dynamic list of possible results. For example, if I typed 'a', '**a**pple', '**a**pples', and 'or**a**nge' would be listed as options. Typing 'ap', would show '**ap**ple' and '**ap**ples', etc.

Should I implement this via a search bar or some sort of filter?  Are there existing code/packages that I can leverage?

Thanks.

Comment: I would take a look at typeahead: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ It does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Is there something in python?

Comment: This can't be "in python". As it involves dynamically altering the page without a page reload, you'll have to have some familiarity with JavaScript.

Comment: @Kye. Is there many a guide about how to integrate this JS to the Django framework? Sorry, I'm quite new to programming. – H C 3 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

I previously posted sample code for it here: [Search engine using python for bookmarked sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272667/search-engine-using-python-for-bookmarked-sites/22273312#22273312)

It takes some thought to understand but the implementation is less than a page of code.